# Adding css and js to Spring project

Tags: java, css, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I know that this question was answered many times on stackoverflow but I can't make it work following the steps on the answers.

First of all what I want is to add some static files (css js img) to my project to access them from html tags.

**My project structure is :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bfVu.jpg

My project works just fine before adding the css but I read in the other posts that I shoud add this line to my dispatcher file :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/jsp/website/" />
```

But when I add it I can no more deploy and get this error :

```
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
```

**Note :**

I changer some thing in the configuration files to remove the .htm extension from the url.

My dispatcher :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="indexContr"/>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the server log for any exceptions? It is strange that deployment is failing. Please check Your_GlassFish_Location\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have mapped as resources all namespace that is available for dispatcher servlet.
   Reduce it from /** to /jsp/website/**

   `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/jsp/website/" />`
2. I would recommend you not to keep static resource under /jsp/, here should be  jsp's =)
   Use "static" or "resources" in path

   `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`

Comment: Yes, Second option is the recommended one.

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved I can now build my project, I have one more problem now when I try to access an image I get HTTP Status 404 - Not Found.. Any help?